# whose view is not in the window hierarchy?

Tags: ios

I call uiviewControllor(ExchangeToday) from another another uiviewcontroller(WelcomeScreen).
but error is:

2013-09-10 11:57:24.005 exchangerate[3234:c07] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

my code is:

```
@interface ExchangeToday : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

UIViewController *second = [[ExchangeToday alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExchangeToday_iPhone" bundle:nil];
second.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
```

How to fix it?

Comment: This means that the `self` view controller isn't yet displayed.

Comment: I might try using just a presentation style OR a Transition style, for testing purposes and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Which are you creating a "UIViewController" or an "ExchangeToday"?

I think your first line should be:

```
      ExchangeToday *second = [[ExchangeToday alloc] initWit hNibName:@"ExchangeToday_iPhone" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: While the `second` variable should have the same type in most cases, using `UIViewController` for the `second` variable is actually just fine in this case and would not be related in any way to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, in my case i was calling

```
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
```

before the calling view (self) finished to present itself. In other words you cannot call the presentModalViewController in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, it as to be in viewDidAppear or well after the view finished loading.

Comment: So if you want the new view to load at the beginning (i.e., pop up a view with a login screen) how would you do that?

Comment: I would put the presentModalView call in applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions . something like this: [rootVC init];  window.rootViewController=rootVC; [rootVC presentModalViewController:loginScreen animated:NO];